# Protractor randomly crashing with ECONNREFUSED

Tags: node.js, protractor

Since a few days, protractor crashes randomly during execution with the following exception:

```
Error: connect ECONNREFUSED
  at errnoException (net.js:905:11)
  at Object.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:896:19)
```

There is no further information given. Catching uncaught errors does not yield any more information as well:

```
{ [Error: connect ECONNREFUSED]
  code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  errno: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  syscall: 'connect' }
```

This happens regardless of running through the webdriver-manager or with directConnect, and regardless of browser (tried chrome and firefox). The console of the webdriver-manager also does not give any indication what could be wrong (output just ends, but is not hung - i.e. I can just start protractor again and connect to the same session).

Tried protractor versions 1.2 and 1.5, as well as node 0.10.31 and 0.10.34 with no change. So I am really at a loss whats going on and how I could debug this problem.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: It connects initially and then disconnects while running tests..is that so?

Comment: @SakshiSingla: yes, browser starts up, runs a variable amount of time (somewhere between a second and a minute) and then DC happens.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like protractor cannot connect to your selenium server. Have you started selenium server before running the tests? (`webdriver-manager start --standalone`). Have you configured protractor to access selenium server through right address/port? (Property `seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub'` in `conf.js`).

Comment: ran standalone, and also crashed _during_ execution, so test starts, spawns a browser, does a few things, crashed. But can't reproduce the issue any more which is super weird :/

Answer (score 0):

I could see from execution error log, The issue is with connection is not established between webdriver server and the browser you use, just follow the below steps, I hope it will work fine,

Step 1: Open Command Prompt type - Webdriver-manager update (To update drivers)

Step 2: Then type - Webdriver-manager start (To Start driver Server)

and make sure, all the configuration details are properly defined in the Configuration file.

I hope this will solve the issue.